# R: No log messages from tidylog

Tags: r, logging, rstudio, tidyr

I installed the tidylog package recently and it was working like a charm. However, it suddenly stopped giving me the log messages, as if it was not installed or not loaded in the library.

I receive no log messages from the following R-Code, for example

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidylog)
library(nycflights13)
filtered <- filter(mtcars, cyl == 4)
mutated <- mutate(mtcars, new_var = wt ** 2)
joined <- left_join(nycflights13::flights, nycflights13::weather,
                    by = c("year", "month", "day", "origin", "hour", "time_hour"))
```

I already uninstalled and installed back R, R-Studio and R-Tools. I already deleted the R-Studio folder in %appdata%, reinstalled tidylog package, but nothing works.

Any help on what could I do?
Best

Comment: Have you tried on a new R session.  I used `packageVersion("tidylog")
[1] ‘1.0.2’` and it is working fine.  `> filtered <- filter(mtcars, cyl == 4)#
filter: removed 21 rows (66%), 11 rows remaining`

Comment: On my machine it works!

Comment: Yes. I've tried a new R session. I also uninstalled and installed back R-Studio. The tidylog version 1.0.2 is correct and loaded. Not working...